# Angular 1.5 nested ng-repeat relation json

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just spent a couple hours to find solution for this issue, but couldn't find any similar problems.

The result should be that materials are linked with colors. I want to display materials and colors and ID of colors in value of ng-option.

View:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>material</label>
            <md-select name="material" ng-model="secondStep.material">
                <md-optgroup label="material">
                    <md-option ng-value="materialsObjs.id" ng-repeat="materialsObjs in materialsObj track by $index">{{materialsObjs.name}}</md-option>
                </md-optgroup>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>colors</label>
            <md-select name="colors" ng-model="secondStep.colors">
                <md-optgroup label="colors">
                    <md-option ng-value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key , value) in colorsObj">{{value}}</md-option>
                </md-optgroup>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "printer_id": 113,
    "materials": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "drewno",
        "color": [{
            "1": "green"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "pla",
        "color": [{
            "3": "yellow"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Controller:

```
if(respondeObj.status == 'ok') {    
    $scope.materialsObj = respondeObj.materials;
    $scope.colorsObj = [];
    angular.forEach(respondeObj.materials, function(value , key) {
        var putish = value.color[0];
        this.push(putish);
    }, $scope.colorsObj);
}
```

I just cant get separated color value for list and color ID to pass as selector value.

Current results is in the image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeaTS.png)

Comment: of course there is an option that there is couple colors related to one material in "color": [{
        "1": "green"
    }]

Comment: Why not make a $scope.currentMaterial variable that stores the current selected material object? Then you can use ng-repeat="color in currentMaterial.colors"

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired "value" you wish to attain? Sorry, it may just be me but Im confused as to what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: @panatoni I have updated my solution to be more straightforward. I forgot about the use of ng-options - this gives you exactly what you are looking for. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is a working solution](http://jsbin.com/butatiz/edit?html,js,output)** based on my comment.

> **EDIT** - I forgot about the ng-optons attribute that allows you to use an object as the selected value for an option. By changing your first select to use ng-options, all you need to add is the **keysFilter** and use the code for the **second dropdown** in my `HTML` section to get the key/value from material.color

#### HTML

```
<select ng-model="currentMaterial"
          ng-options="material as material.name for material in materialsObj"></select>
<select ng-if="currentMaterial">
  <option ng-repeat="color in currentMaterial.color" value="{{id}}" ng-init="id = (color | keysFilter)">{{color[id]}}</option>
</select>
```

#### AngularJS Controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.filter("keysFilter", function () {
  return (function (item){
    if (!item) {
      return [];
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(item);
    return keys[0];
  });
})
.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope){
  $scope.currentMaterial = {};
  $scope.materialsObj = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "drewno",
      "color": [
        {
          "1": "green"
        },
        {
          "2": "yellow"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "pla",
      "color": [
        {
          "3": "yellow"
        },
        {
          "4": "purple"
        },
        {
          "5": "brown"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly your problem is because after you construct *$scope.colorsObj* array you will have objects in it:

```
$scope.colorsObj  = [
    {"1": "green"},
    {"3": "yellow"}
];
```

and then you would need to have another ***ng-repeat*** to achieve what you want, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in colorsObj">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: OP wants <select>, not <div>.

Comment: @mhodges it was just to explain what's causing the problem

Comment: "you would need to have another ng-repeat to achieve what you want" While your code would work for your example, it would not work for the OP because you cannot have nested ng-repeats inside of <select>. I think this is just a fundamentally flawed way of approaching the problem.

Comment: actually this is what I wanted achieve , but still have this issue , as you said cant have nested ng-repeat in ng-repeat in select...

Comment: I dont know if its hmm perfectly ok but basicly it  works when I do like this    <md-optgroup label="colors">
                        <p ng-repeat="colors in colorsObj">
                        <md-option ng-value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key,value) in colors">{{ value }}</md-option>
                        </p>
                    </md-optgroup>

Comment: @panatoni yes that's why I wanted to only to mention what's the source of the problem. The approach of how you want to refactor or implement it depends on you and how you decide, because I haven't understood quite well how you want to present the results.

Comment: @panatoni Have you looked at my solution? It's exactly what you are trying to do..